# Loading spinner does not show while navigating between pages in a Nuxt 3 application

Tags: navigation, vuejs3, loader, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 + Vue 3 application. I have 2 pages

1. `pages/index.vue` file as my home page
2. `pages/folder1/folder2/[dynamic_route].vue`

When navigating from my home page to the other page, my loading spinner does not show up immediately. Initially, the page stays on the home page and after sometime when it actually navigates to the second page, then the loading-spinner shows up briefly and the chart is displayed.

I expected the loading spinner to show as soon as I navigate to the other page. However, this is not the way it works.

Question: How can I make the loading spinner to show up immediately upon navigating to the other page.

NOTE: I have 3 API calls being used in this page, here I have displayed only one. Not sure if this is causing that problem.

Below is my code:

`nuxt.config.ts` file has the route rule for making this page client-side rendering.

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...  
  routeRules: {
    "@/pages/folder1/folder2/**": { ssr: false },
  },
  ...
});
```

`pages/index.vue` home page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Please standby for more products!</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

`pages/folder1/folder2/[dynamic_route].vue` page

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading" class="loader">Loading...</div>

    <div v-else class="chartSection">
      <div v-if="!error && !pending" class="chart">
        <ApexchartsLineChart :top20-items="top20Items" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { createError } from "h3";
definePageMeta({ middleware: "auth" });

const baseURL = `/api/proxy/some_path`;
const route = useRoute();
const dynamicRoute = route.params.dynamic_route;

const loading = ref(true);
onMounted(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.value = false;
  }, 300);
});

// Fetch data
const {
  data,
  error,
  pending,
} = await useFetch(`${baseURL}/another_path/${dynamicRoute}`);

if (error?.value || !data?.value) {
  throw createError({
    message: "Error in data section",
    statusCode: error.value?.statusCode,
    statusMessage: error.value?.statusMessage,
    fatal: true,
  });
}

const top20Items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data?.value?.slice(0, 20)));
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "@/assets/styles/loaders/loadingDotsSpinner.scss";
@import "@/assets/styles/pages/chartPage.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: You might try phrasing your title as a question to allow those reading it to get the gist of the question faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the `NuxtLoadingIndicator` component.
Like in the below code:

```
<template>
  <NuxtLoadingIndicator />
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

I would suggest you configure the `NuxtLoadingIndicator` component's throttle from default `200` to something less (even `0`).

Because https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/routing/pages says "Throttle the appearing and hiding, in milliseconds (default 200).
"

Answer (score 0):

`onMounted` is not going to work here like that because by the time its been allowed to mount, the API has already loaded because the top level await is on the API call that is suspending the components mount method, you should call the API inside of `onMounted` so that your loading indicator is given a chance to actually render like so:

```js
loading.value = true

onMounted(async () => {
  const { data, error, pending,} = await useFetch(...);

  ...

  loading.value = false;
});
```

However... Since you have a top level script `await` already you should be able to leverage the built in Nuxt Loading Indicator and throw away that loading ref concept:

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-loading-indicator#nuxtloadingindicator

Also make sure you are on Nuxt version `3.5.1+` as there where some bug fixes around suspense in last couple of weeks.

Comment: I tried adding the `<NuxtLoadingIndicator \>` to the `pages/folder1/folder2/[dynamic_route].vue` page but, it does not work. I also tried adding it to the `layouts`, still does not work, also added it to my `index.vue` file, still not working.